# Fql access error in C# .net?

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to access the following info using FQL in c# .However am getting an HTTP bad request error

```
string Frnds = api.Get("/fql?q=SELECT+uid+name+username+locale+affiliations+timezone+birthday+sex+proxied_email+current_location+FROM+user+WHERE+uid=me()");
```

Is there some problem with my query , It seems to look fine to me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried separating each field name with a comma (,) then urlencoding it

you can test out your query here - please note in the following link I added in ","

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=fql%3Fq%3DSELECT%20uid%2C%20name%2C%20username%2C%20locale%2C%20affiliations%2C%20timezone%2C%20birthday%2C%20sex%2C%20proxied_email%20%2Ccurrent_location%20FROM%20user%20WHERE%20uid%3Dme%28%29

your query can't parse the fields correctly

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=fql%3Fq%3DSELECT%20uid%20name%20username%20locale%20affiliations%20timezone%20birthday%20sex%20proxied_email%20current_location%20FROM%20user%20WHERE%20uid%3Dme%28%29

Comment: Its showing on the graph explorer but not on my webpage as in my asp.net web application

Comment: my point was in the query you have up above, there aren't any commas separating the fields you want returned so instead of "select+uid+name" you need "select+uid,+name. If you changed the fields to select * i'm assuming it might also work

Comment: ok, well the http bad request error implies you are sending a malformed request, try this and see if it works. 

string Frnds = api.Get("/fql?q=SELECT%20uid%2C%20name%2C%20username%2C%20locale%2C%20affiliations%2C%20timezone%2C%20birthday%2C%20sex%2C%20proxied_email%2C%20current_location%2C%20FROM%20user%20WHERE%20uid=me()");

Comment: And can you confirm what c# sdk adn version you are using?

Comment: what was the solution? As it might prove helpful to others